# Probability measures on the class of nonempty compact subsets

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

Let

$$\mathcal{C}(\Bbb R^n) = \{A \subseteq \Bbb R^n \mid A \neq \emptyset, A \textrm{ compact}\}.$$

I am curious about whether there are some notable probability spaces defined on $\mathcal{C}(\Bbb R^n).$ Formally, does there exists a well known (relative to the people in the filed) $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{C}(\Bbb R^n)$ and a probability measure $\Bbb P: \mathcal{A} \to [0,1]$ such that $(\mathcal{C}(\Bbb R^n), \mathcal{A}, \Bbb P)$ is a probability space? This sounds like something that is well studied, but I was unable to find on my search. In case it exists, a description of the probability space would be highly appreciated. Otherwise, it will be enough to have any reference in the literature.

Comment: You can furnish $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the Hausdorff metric, $d_H(A,B) = \max \left(  \sup_{x \in B} (x,A), \sup_{y \in A} (y, B) \right)$, which now allows you to place a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. You can construct a metric outer measure on this space, although I'm not familiar with any notable examples. Perhaps these ideas can help with your search?

Comment: @JoseAvilez thanks for keywords! I will take a look at them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_compact_set